# Angular 10.1 Ivy doesn't understand *ngFor directive

Tags: angular, pug, angular-ivy

Since my upgrading from Angular 10 to 10.1, my ivy compiler have started to misread ngFor directives.

e.g.

```
mat-grid-tile(
    *ngFor='let preview of previewList; trackBy: trackByFn'
    )
    img.previews__img(
      #previewImage,
      )
    mat-icon(
      (click)='deletePreview(preview.name)',
      ) delete
    canvas.previews__canvas(
      #previewCanvas
      )
    .previews__name {{preview.name}}
```

Ivy randomly advice me:

> error TS2339: Property 'preview' does not exist on type

It's trivial that `preview` it's a property inside `*ngFor` directive scope, but Ivy seems not understand that.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can u reconfirm by creating a demo on stackbltz.com

Answer (score 0):

Close your running server. Start ng serve again.